# Power series and shifting index

Tags: integration, summation, power-series, index-notation

First I have to find the power series represantion for the following function:

$$\ f(x) = \ln(1+x)$$

I tried the following:

$$\ \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\ln(1+x)\Big) = \frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^n$$

Therefore,

$$\ f(x) = \ln(1+x) = \int\sum_{n=0}^\infty{}(-x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{n+1}}{n+1} $$

Up to this point I think my answer is correct, but I have to shift the index by one so it starts from

***n = 1*** and I get:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n}$$

I need some help in this last part if everything above is correct

Comment: Try writing out the first few terms

Comment: Yes it looks familiar. Just add a $dx$ to the integral and there is a theorem for when one is allowed to move integrals in under sum signs, but I forgot the name for it, but I am kind of sure you are allowed to do that there.

Comment: @qbert what first terms?

Comment: If the indices are increased by $c$, you have to replace $n$ by $n-c$. Your approach is perfectly right.

Comment: @c2J of your series. It should help make clear that the series with the shifted index is the same

Comment: @Peter so is my answer correct? I am not getting full points for that answer :(

Comment: You forgot a minus sign...

Comment: @Peter I'm just asked to write the power series representation of the function starting at n = 1. The software for the homework is not giving me full points for that answer so I guess is wrong but you say is right :S... I also found the radius of convergence which is 1, and for that I'm getting all points

Comment: which part is wrong? can you write the answer to this post?

Comment: @c2J Did my answer help you understanding what went wrong ?

Comment: absolutely!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write $$(-x)^n=(-1)^{n}\cdot x^n$$ If you integrate that you have $${(-1)}^n\cdot \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ Shifting gives $${(-1)}^{n-1}\cdot \frac{x^n}{n}=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot \frac{x^n}{n}$$ So your approach was correct, but you forgot to seperate the sign before integrating.

Comment: You are right, but that is not a problem if he instead remembers the internal derivative (chain rule). $D(f(g(x))) = g'(x)f'(g(x))$

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, but I think this way it is easier.

Comment: Yes it is a good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Index shifting is simple:

$$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n)$$

can be rewritten with a variable substitution, for instance $n\to m+s$

$$\sum_{m+s=a}^b f(m+s)$$ or

$$\sum_{m=a-s}^{b-s} f(m+s).$$

If you want a specific starting value, choose the suitable $s$.